# GHC/GCC compiler issue __STDC_VERSION__ w/ C99 from Stg.h, fails for every package

Tags: haskell, gcc, cabal

Whenever I try to install a package with cabal(2.0.0) on OSX 10.12.6 and GCC 4.8.0, I am met with the following error regarding the Stg.h file from GHC 8.2.1, the error is incredibly cryptic. I can't install any package on OSX.

Expected behavior:

`cabal install $packagename` should install `$packagename` on OSX, since cabal and cabal-install are properly installed.

Observed behavior:

`cabal install $packagename` fails due to a low-level GHC/GCC issue related to a variable called `__STDC_VERSION__`. I am not a C programmer and I don't expect my proper install of GHC and cabal to fail to install packages. AFAICT this issue is not related to user error.

```
Matthew@Mattmac git:the_D*+ ~/Projects/kata/euler>cabal update && cabal 
install optparse-applicative
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘16.7.0
gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘16.7.0
Warning: --root-cmd is no longer supported, see
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/3353 (if you didn't type --root-cmd,
comment out root-cmd in your ~/.cabal/config file)
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading transformers-compat-0.5.1.4...
Configuring colour-2.3.4...
Configuring transformers-compat-0.5.1.4...
Building colour-2.3.4...
Building transformers-compat-0.5.1.4...
Failed to install transformers-compat-0.5.1.4
Build log ( /Users/Matthew/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.2.1/transformers-compat-0.5.1.4-HHfl4KyHCH71PMx2CRgdve.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/qw/k0t4r5fd5_b0phjvwtxx_n700000gq/T/cabal-tmp-91946/transformers-compat-0.5.1.4'
Configuring transformers-compat-0.5.1.4...
gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘16.7.0
Preprocessing library for transformers-compat-0.5.1.4..
Building library for transformers-compat-0.5.1.4..
[1 of 2] Compiling Control.Monad.Trans.Instances ( src/Control/Monad/Trans/Instances.hs, dist/build/Control/Monad/Trans/Instances.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Paths_transformers_compat ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_transformers_compat.hs, dist/build/Paths_transformers_compat.o )
[1 of 2] Compiling Control.Monad.Trans.Instances ( src/Control/Monad/Trans/Instances.hs, dist/build/Control/Monad/Trans/Instances.p_o )
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/8.2.1-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-8.2.1/include/Rts.h:30:0: error:
    0,
                     from /var/folders/qw/k0t4r5fd5_b0phjvwtxx_n700000gq/T/ghc92089_0/ghc_7.c:2:

/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/8.2.1-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-8.2.1/include/Stg.h:30:3: error:
     error: #error __STDC_VERSION__ does not advertise C99 or later
     # error __STDC_VERSION__ does not advertise C99 or later
       ^
   |
30 | # error __STDC_VERSION__ does not advertise C99 or later
   |   ^
`gcc' failed in phase `C Compiler'. (Exit code: 1)
cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/qw/k0t4r5fd5_b0phjvwtxx_n700000gq/T/cabal-tmp-91946/transformers-compat-0.5.1.4'
Failed to install colour-2.3.4
Build log ( /Users/Matthew/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.2.1/colour-2.3.4-9c0ktEQZfar3Wigr5kT6BU.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/qw/k0t4r5fd5_b0phjvwtxx_n700000gq/T/cabal-tmp-91945/colour-2.3.4'
Configuring colour-2.3.4...
Preprocessing library for colour-2.3.4..
Building library for colour-2.3.4..
[ 1 of 14] Compiling Data.Colour.CIE.Chromaticity ( 
Data/Colour/CIE/Chromaticity.hs, dist/build/Data/Colour/CIE/Chromaticity.o )
...
[ 1 of 14] Compiling Data.Colour.CIE.Chromaticity ( Data/Colour/CIE/Chromaticity.hs, dist/build/Data/Colour/CIE/Chromaticity.p_o )

In file included from /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/8.2.1-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-8.2.1/include/Rts.h:30:0: error:
    0,
                     from /var/folders/qw/k0t4r5fd5_b0phjvwtxx_n700000gq/T/ghc92201_0/ghc_3.c:2:

/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/8.2.1-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-8.2.1/include/Stg.h:30:3: error:
     error: #error __STDC_VERSION__ does not advertise C99 or later
     # error __STDC_VERSION__ does not advertise C99 or later
       ^
   |
30 | # error __STDC_VERSION__ does not advertise C99 or later
   |   ^
`gcc' failed in phase `C Compiler'. (Exit code: 1)
cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/qw/k0t4r5fd5_b0phjvwtxx_n700000gq/T/cabal-tmp-91945/colour-2.3.4'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ansi-terminal-0.7.1.1-3eOIKoB8mo97DkHMJ6AgBw depends on ansi-terminal-0.7.1.1
which failed to install.
ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.1-Ctcte9oFd5tFGoIV7u576g depends on
ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.1 which failed to install.
colour-2.3.4-9c0ktEQZfar3Wigr5kT6BU failed during the building phase. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
optparse-applicative-0.14.0.0-Iaq7kOKFg2Z4XsKvk269H6 depends on
optparse-applicative-0.14.0.0 which failed to install.
transformers-compat-0.5.1.4-HHfl4KyHCH71PMx2CRgdve failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: This is incredibly frustrating. We had to alter the GHC include files to remove them, because it's been many months and there's still no fix to this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the error is incredibly cryptic

Actually, it looks pretty clear:

```
error: #error __STDC_VERSION__ does not advertise C99 or later
```

The C header file `Stg.h` is checking whether the compiler supports C99 (the 1999 version of the standard ISO C), using the standard macro `__STDC_VERSION__`. Since that is not set accordingly, the compiler is not C99 compliant, and the C source triggers an error.

Basically, `Stg.h` refuses to compile with a C compiler which does not even support the 18 years old C standard. Quite reasonable.

GCC 4.8 indeed looks ancient: the latest GCC is 7.1. I'd try to upgrade GCC to a more recent version, if not the latest.

---

Update: as Keith Thompson pointed out below, GCC 4.8, in spite of its age, can support C99 if passed the flag `-std=c99`. There should be some way to instruct `cabal` to pass on this flag to `gcc`, but I can't remember how. There should be some option named something like `cflags` for this, somehwere.

Comment: Since the error has nothing to do with Haskell or the install, I'd argue that the error is quite peripheral to the installed system. GCC 4.2/4.8 are routinely used in enterprise systems and version requirements aren't mentioned in the Haskell system documentation (rare mentions can be found in the ghci standalone for older versions of GHC, and LLVM in the newer standalones). `brew upgrade gcc` and aliasing gcc solved the issue. Thank you @chi

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to upgrade gcc.  gcc 4.8.0 was released in 2013. It doesn't support C99 *by default*. You just need to invoke it with `-std=c99` (to support C99) or `-std=gnu99` (to support C99 with GNU extensions). The default language version is `-std=gnu89`. For more recent releases, the default is `-std=gnu11`. (But if you've upgraded gcc anyway, that should also solve it.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah, right. That's an excellent advice. I can't remember how to convince `cabal` to pass on that flag, but it should be doable.